# Angular ng-cloak wait child directive template to load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngcloak

My problem is that when I use ng-cloak in pages that include elements which make use of directives with template code, ng-cloak does not wait for this template code to load and the page is shown incrementally and not as a whole (page elements first and after a while template code pops out).

I have tried to make a custom ng-cloak directive so that it won't remove element's ng-cloak class while any child element contains ng-cloak class but with no success. I thought this one would be a common issue, but I have not managed to find a solution online. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle with the problem?

Comment: @Plantface Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it in a simple jsFiddle example. But I think I have found a site that uses Angular and this 'problem' occurs, but I am not sure, am I allowed to post its link as an example here?

Comment: I think so, as long as it is a means to illustrate a problem and not an ends to spam, you're golden

Comment: Ok, it's just used as an example. I found [Registro](http://registro.br/) uses AngularJs. If you check page source you will see that the green thing in the middle which says 'Pesquise e registre o domínio desejado' is a directive (searchdomain). If you notice when reloading the page, this is not shown immediately. That's what I am referring to.

Comment: @gosling So you mean when the document fully loaded then you want your directive to be rendered? Can't you reproduce this with your code in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [ngCloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) was designed to cloak your content until *everything* is loaded. It is designed to prevent your content to be rendered in its *raw* form, what with expressions and all.

However, according to the documentation, it might work on the `body` element, but I haven't verified it myself:

> **The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element**, but the preferred
>   usage is to apply multiple `ngCloak` directives to small portions of the
>   page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

Comment: I have tried to put it to the <body> element but with no success. I understand that ngCloak may not be suitable, but I was wondering if anyone found the situation I describe annoying and found a solution (even without ngCloak)?